# Batching in Custom Functions using Office JS

Tags: office-js

I was stuck in that getting array of excel rows (when dragging multiple rows) from excel to customfunction.js file using JSON file. I tried with dimentionality as "matrix" instead "scalar" but still I am getting single value from excel when dragging multiple selections.

For example, if i type custom formulae in one cell and entered then corresponding input value able to get in .js file but when we dragged multiple rows how to get values from single api call in .js file.

Thanks
Murugananth S

Comment: Hi Team, Any update please...

Comment: Can you please confirm whether Batching, which allows to aggregate multiple calls to the same function can be achieved in Office JS Excel Api?

Comment: Hi Team, any update on this?